# Set property in custom dialog for conditional feature

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a property called SELECTEDFEATURESET with a default value of 'none'.  In a custom dialog I'm trying to set this property, according to which button the user pressed. At the end I use the property to decide if certain components shall be installed or not.

Propery defined in the main installer file (Product.wxs):

```
<Property Id='SELECTEDFEATURESET' Value='none' />
```

Set the property in the dialog:

```
<Control Id="InternalFeatureButton" Type="PushButton" Text="FeatureSetA">
  <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Property="SELECTEDFEATURESET" Value="FeatureSetA">1</Publish>
</Control>
<Control Id="ProductionFeatureButton" Type="PushButton" Text="FeatureSetB">
    <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg">1</Publish>
    <Publish Property="SELECTEDFEATURESET" Value="FeatureSetB">1</Publish>
</Control>
<Control Id="DemoFeatureButton" Type="PushButton" Text="FeatureSetC">
    <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg">1</Publish>
    <Publish Property="SELECTEDFEATURESET" Value="FeatureSetC">1</Publish>
</Control>
```

Decide whether the feature shall be installed or not:

```
<Feature Id='ParentFeature' Level='0'>
  <ComponentRef Id='ComponentA' />
  <Condition Level='1'><![CDATA[SELECTEDFEATURESET="FeatureSetA"]]></Condition>
</Feature>
<Feature Id='ParentFeature' Level='0'>
  <ComponentRef Id='ComponentB' />
  <Condition Level='1'><![CDATA[SELECTEDFEATURESET="FeatureSetB"]]></Condition>
</Feature>
<Feature Id='ParentFeature' Level='0'>
  <ComponentRef Id='ComponentC' />
  <Condition Level='1'><![CDATA[SELECTEDFEATURESET="FeatureSetC"]]></Condition>
</Feature>
```

When I run the installer and press the FeatureSetA button, no optional component is installed. When I initialize the SELECTEDFEATURESET property with 'FeatureSetA', then the ComponentA is installed (same for A, B and C).

Why is the value of SELECTEDFEATURESET 'none' instead of 'FeatureSetA' / 'FeatureSetB' / 'FeatureSetC' at the time of the feature condition evaluation?
How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it my moving the condition from the feature to the component.